# Magnetic forces do no wok

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

[image]
The magnetic field is pointing upwards and uniform.

Part C:

Since the magnetic field does not do any work, the initial velocity of the bar should remain constant through time.
But in the solution of the problem, the velocity is a function of time. Can anyone please explain this inconsistency?

Comment: The concept of *upwards*, looking at the figure, is at least ambiguous. Do you mean that it points out the plane containing the circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A force can change momentum in two ways: 1. Increasing the magnitude, and 2. Changing the direction.

An increase in magnitude corresponds to work done, since kinetic energy is related to the magnitude of momentum as $K = \frac{p^2}{2m}$. A change in direction corresponds to reallocating the kinetic energy from the momentum in one direction to the momentum in another since $K = \frac{p^2}{2m} = \frac{p_x^2}{2m} + \frac{p_y^2}{2m} = K_x + K_y$.

The magnetic field is a purely "direction changing" force, and the simplest proof of this is showing that the rate of work done, power, is always 0:
$$P_B = \mathbf F_B\cdot\mathbf v = q(\mathbf v\times\mathbf B)\cdot \mathbf v = 0$$
since $(\mathbf a\times\mathbf b)\cdot\mathbf a = 0$ for any vectors $\mathbf a,\mathbf b$.

The magnetic force *does* do work on the charges as it rotates their momentum vector, but in two parts. Negative work must be done on the charges to take the energy from one direction, and positive work must be done on the charges to give the energy to the other direction. It is always the case that these two quantities of work are equal in magnitude so that the total work done by the magnetic force is 0.

In this specific problem the magnetic field does negative work against the charges as they move in the horizontal direction which causes the bar to slow down, but it also does positive work on the charges as they move in the vertical direction to maintain a current in the loop against the resistor. We already know from $P_B = 0$ that these contributions cancel, but we will see explicitly that all energy taken from the rod is dissipated by the resistor (which does work with an electric field).

I took "The magnetic field is upwards and uniform" to mean along $\hat y$ but that leads to a trivial problem so I'll assume the magnetic field is $\mathbf B = -B\hat z$ (pointing into the page).

The velocity of the charges in the rod is
$$\mathbf v_q = (\text{speed of rod})\hat x + (\frac{\text{CCW current}}{\text{charge density}})\hat y = v\hat x + \frac{I}{\lambda}\hat y$$

The total magnetic force on the charges in the rod (length $l$) is
$$\mathbf F_B = q \mathbf v_q\times \mathbf B = \lambda l(v\hat x + \frac{I}{\lambda}\hat y)\times(-B\hat z) = (\lambda vlB) \hat y - (IlB)\hat x$$

The work being done by the magnetic force to decelerate the rod in the x direction can be expressed in terms of power as
$$(P_B)_x = (F_B)_x(v_q)_x = -vIlB$$

And similarly the rate of work done to keep current flowing in the y direction is
$$(P_B)_y = (F_B)_y(v_q)_y = vIlB$$

And as expected we have $(P_B)_x = -(P_B)_y \implies P_B = 0$.

We can see that the magnetic force acts by taking energy from the motion of the rod to do work on the charges around the loop. If there was an inductor in the loop instead of the resistor then the current would stay constant as the energy transfers to the inductor and the rod slows down. However in this case with the resistor we can see from Kirchhoff's laws that all energy transferred from the rod is dissipated as heat
$$P_{loop} = 0 \implies (P_B)_y + P_R = 0 \implies (P_B)_x = -I^2 R$$

In conclusion, the total work done by the magnetic force is 0 but it certainly does do work in the process of slowing down the rod as it transfers energy from the rod's motion into the circuit to be dissipated by the resistor.

**I should mention that as the current decreases in the loop there is an induced electric field which also contributes to the work done but it's generally negligible considering the small inductance of a loop like the one in this problem.